# Used Json Layout template but getting parameters missing in logs [log4j2]

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I used Json layout template in my project but I am getting the logs with few parameters missing. I have tried to mention those missing parameters in pattern itself but I guess that was not a right approach to get those parameters in my logs. Any suggestion on that?

```
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT


logger.rolling.name = SD
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RALLog

status = error
dest = err

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = trace

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern =%C{0}.%M:(%L) - %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = error

#File Appender for JSON log file.
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RALLog
appender.rolling.fileName = SD/sac.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = SD/sac/sac-{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = JsonTemplateLayout
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
```

Comment: Please add your Log4j configuration and JSON template to your question.

Comment: Not sure about Json template in my application.

Comment: I thought you were using the _"JSON template layout"_, the deprecated _"JSON layout"_ has a fixed template.

Comment: sorry my bad. I had used JsonTemplateLayout in my properties file. I have updated the properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark**: [`JsonLayout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout) is considered deprecated. You should use [`JsonTemplateLayout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) instead. The latter is the equivalent of `PatternLayout` for JSON-based layouts.

If you are referring to the missing location info (the equivalent of the `%C`, `%M` and `%L` patterns, cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout)), it is an expensive operation and it is not generated by default, because it decreases logging performance considerably.

To enable it use:

```
appender.rolling.layout.type = JsonLayout
appender.rolling.layout.locationInfo = true
```

**Edit**: If you switch to `JsonTemplateLayout`, you need to set `locationInfoEnabled` to true:

```
appender.rolling.layout.type = JsonTemplateLayout
appender.rolling.layout.locationInfoEnabled = true
```

Moreover the [default template](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-layout-template-json/src/main/resources/EcsLayout.json) does not contain any location information, so you need to add it using `EventTemplateAdditionalField`s:

```
appender.rolling.layout.0.type = EventTemplateAdditionalField
appender.rolling.layout.0.key = log.origin.file.name
appender.rolling.layout.0.value = {"$resolver": "source", "field": "fileName"}
appender.rolling.layout.0.format = JSON
appender.rolling.layout.1.type = EventTemplateAdditionalField
appender.rolling.layout.1.key = log.origin.function
appender.rolling.layout.1.value = {"$resolver": "source", "field": "methodName"}
appender.rolling.layout.1.format = JSON
appender.rolling.layout.2.type = EventTemplateAdditionalField
appender.rolling.layout.2.key = log.origin.file.line
appender.rolling.layout.2.value = {"$resolver": "source", "field": "lineNumber"}
appender.rolling.layout.2.format = JSON
```

Comment: I have used **appender.rolling.layout.locationInfo = true** in my log4j2.properties file but still same issue. Some of the parameters are not reflecting.

Comment: Which parameters?

Comment: "source_host", "file_name", "version", "method_name", "mdc" etc. These are the parameters which are missing in my logs.
And also by default I am getting "ecs.version" in my logs after using JsonTemplateLayout which actually I don't want in my logs.

Comment: How to mention these parameters in log file itself, as **layout.pattern** in not allowed in case of jsonTemplateLayout.

Comment: @007_programmer: check the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#event-template-resolvers) on how to add additional fields to your JSON objects. I added an example in the answer. BTW: if your main output is JSON a [`log4j2.json`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#JSON) file is much more compact than a `log4j2.properties` file (in reality any configuration format is more compact).

Comment: Shall I put one question here as it is related to above question.

Comment: @007_programmer: post a new question and link to this one for reference.